# Permission problems with .NET web client application

Tags: c#, .net, permissions

I am attempting to run a C# web client application on a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine with something along the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;

namespace willitwork
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
                // Create web client.
                WebClient client = new WebClient();

                // Download string.
                string value = client.DownloadString("http://www.dotnetperls.com/");

                // Write values.
                Console.WriteLine("--- WebClient result ---");
                Console.WriteLine(value.Length);
                Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the application as the administrator everything works fine:

```
C:\moop>whoami
p10uc2\administrator

C:\moop>willitwork.exe
--- WebClient result ---
3336
<!doctype html><html><head><link rel=canonical href=http://www.dotnetperls.com><style>body{font:18px/1.45 verdana;position:relative;padding:0 0 330px;min-width:
750px;max-width:960px;margin:0 auto}...

    etc.
```

However, when deployed, the application will be launched by system. I switch to the system user and run the application again, just to be faced with this:

```
c:\moop>whoami
nt authority\system

c:\moop>willitwork.exe

Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made becaus
e the target machine actively refused it 54.240.176.85:80
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state,
IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(String address)
   at willitwork.Program.Main()
```

For some reason this does not seem to be an issue on Windows 7. I would be grateful for any hints on what I may be doing wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution after looking at [this page.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/29a8831a-6251-47e5-90a3-dfe4c87ff20e/systemnetsocketssocketexception-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively?forum=netfxnetcom)

The problem is to do with proxies and that, apparently, the application uses IE's proxy settings. In the application these can be set either programmatically by loading proxy information into the client object:

```
client.Proxy = new WebProxy(new Uri("http://proxy.oursite.com:8080"), true);
```

or by changing the app.conf file of the application by adding:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy>
    <proxy 
        usesystemdefault="True"
        proxyaddress=http://proxy.oursite.com:8080
        bypassonlocal="True"
    />
 </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```